# Android RelativeLayout Background Color

Tags: android, colors, background, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

For a long time I am reading posts from stackoverflow because they are very helpful and google seems to think that also.

Since yesterday I have a problem with a row in a ListView in Android. I want to show an image and the area between the image and the bottom of the element should be filled with a grey color.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ConversationsBadgeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <QuickContactBadge
            android:id="@+id/ConversationsBadge"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
    ...
    A LinearLayout with TextViews, shouldn't be interesting for this
    ...
    -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Problem ist that the it seems that the inner layout only wraps the content but doesn't fill_parent. When I set for example 100dp it works but that is not what i want.

It would be nice if you could help me with that. I tried much workarround like using LinearLayouts and TextViews but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background color to the `ListView` itself, then everything in it will have the background you want.

BTW, I recommend using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` in your case.

Comment: I simply changed the Layouts to LinearLayout and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The layout file should contain exactly one outermost element and it should have both android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent"  Your RelativeLayout has android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use you can take background color in  another xml file and put in drawable folder and also using Linear Layout is very useful to your problem